# Laravel E-Commerce, with multiple, options ie colour, size and stock

Tags: laravel-5

I'm building a ecommerce system and I have clothing items that can be the same item, but with 3/4 different colours, sizes and stock.

I'm struggling to get my head around how I can make this work, to show all colours that have stock then display all the size available for these items that have stock. I also don't know how I should setup the database to allow for this, so any help greatful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the one main product in the database without adding extra records for the variants you can save something like this in a text field:

**Field: variants (text)**

```
215465|Blue|s:10,m:4,l:45,xl:40
215466|Red|s:8,m:10,l:29,xl:5
```

**Or better, with array's:**

```
[
    '215465' => [
        'blue' => [
            's'  => 10, 
            'm'  => 4, 
            'l'  => 45, 
            'xl' => 40
         ],
    ],
    '215466' => [
        'red' => [
            's'  => 8, 
            'm'  => 10, 
            'l'  => 29, 
            'xl' => 5
         ]
    ],
]
```

What I would do is saving it as a Json string so Laravel is able to [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) it to the right format (Easy to access afterwards). The first option takes a little more effort to serialize to Json but is more readible for the non technician that is going to use it.

If you are building a Laravel CMS to maintain this data then you can build a nice interface to create and maintain the necessary Json instead of having to type it manually yourself.

Comment: Would a separate table titled "size", with all the different sizes, and then creating a one-to-many relationship also work?